# HTML links that close UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview, safari

I have a normal HTML page with a few links.
When this html page is loaded in UIWebView, and a link is clicked, it should open in safar and NOT UIWebView.

I think i can't use this code:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
   // NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest Loading: %@", [request URL]);
   return TRUE;
}
```

... because it's for Apps and it wouldn't work on a html page, right?

Thanx
M.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you want to open a link in Safar i you do this -

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.co.uk"]];`

But since you are in `UIWebView` you cannot do this.

So for this what you need to do is implement `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` delegate of `UIWebView`. Whenever a link is clicked in `UIWebView` this delegate is called. Now you can decide to do what you want. In this case you want to open this link in Safari. So the code goes like this, to quote -

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    NSURL *requestURL =[[ request URL ] retain]; 
    if (([[ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ] || 
         [[ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"https" ] || 
         [[ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"mailto" ]) 
        && ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) ) 
    { 
        return ![[ UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [requestURL autorelease]]; 
    } 
    [requestURL release]; 
    return YES; 
}
```

So the above code opens every `http://, https://, and mailto://` URL open in the external Safari or Mail applications.

Also to have only select URLs launch Safari, you could change their scheme from http:// to `safari://` or something similar, and only kick those URLs off to the system (after replacing the custom URL scheme with `http://`).

I do this within my internal help documentation, which is HTML displayed in a UIWebView, so that I don't run into issues in the review process with having a general-purpose web browser embedded in my application.

Answer (score 0):

use This one

```
  -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView1 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

        NSURL *requestURL = [[ request URL] retain];
        NSString *str_url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",requestURL];
        if([str_url isEqualToString:@"about:blank"]){
            [requestURL release];
            return YES;
        }else{
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
        }   
        [requestURL release];
        return NO;
    }
```